# Converting between confidence interval and standard error

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error

In this [link](https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_7/7_7_7_2_obtaining_standard_errors_from_confidence_intervals_and.htm) it says that we can convert a 95% confidence interval to the standard error by this calculation:

$$SE = (upper limit – lower limit) / 3.92$$

For 90% confidence intervals divide by 3.29 rather than 3.92; for 99% confidence intervals divide by 5.15.

I am trying to figure out how this factor of 3.92 (and 3.29 and 5.15) is reached. My initial thought is to divide the 95'th percentile with the 84' percentile as a way to find the scaling factor between the widths of the 90% and 68% confidence interval: `qnorm(0.975) / qnorm(0.84)`. However, this gives 1.97 which is more of less half of 3.92

So apparently the factors come from `2 * qnorm(0.975) / qnorm(0.84)`. Why do we need the factor of 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A 95 % confidence interval is obtained from the SE by multiplying it with `qnorm(0.975) = 1.959964` in both directions.

$CI_h = \hat{x} + SE \cdot 1.959964$

So suppose the mean is 7 and SE in 1, then the 95 % CI is `[7-1*qnorm(0.975), 7+1*qnorm(0.975)] = [5.040036, 8.959964]`.

So if you have a 95 % CI you can invert the previous formula for

$SE=\frac{CI_h-\hat{x}}{1.959964}$

to get back the SE `(8.959964 - 7) / 1.959964 = 1`.

**Edit**

$CI_l=\hat{x} - SE \cdot 1.959964$ and $CI_h=\hat{x} + SE \cdot 1.959964$

then

$CI_h-CI_l=\hat{x} + SE \cdot 1.959964 - (\hat{x} - SE \cdot 1.959964)$
$CI_h-CI_l=2 \cdot SE \cdot 1.959964$
$CI_h-CI_l=3.919928 \cdot SE$
$\frac{CI_h-CI_l}{3.919928}=SE$

Comment: So the factors in the link are wrong?

Comment: @TylerD No, different approaches to obtain the same result.

Comment: But how do they get their factors then? I agree with your approach by the way

Comment: @TylerD See edit.